# Generate the output on a particular cell ID in CSV

Tags: perl, csv, automation

What I am trying to achieve here is to extract the **values** from  *tags* HTML to a CSV file which I am succesful. What I want to is to get some *control* over the output being generated.

HTML values are:

```
<input type=hidden id=batterystatus value="Charging" >
<input type=hidden id=batterylevel value="80&nbsp;%" >
<input type=hidden id=signalStrength value="4" >
<input type=hidden id=ulCurrentDataRate value="5 Kbps" >
<input type=hidden id=dlCurrentDataRate value="136 Kbps" >
<input type=hidden id=ConnectionTime value="00:15:33:10" >
<input type=hidden id=noOfClient value="2" >
```

Now, I wrote the script using **perl**.

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $url = 'http://192.168.225.1';
my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(url => $url);
my %tags;
while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('input')) {
           my $id=$tag->get_attr('id'); # get id attribute value    
           my $value = $tag->get_attr('value'); # get value attribute value
           $tags{$id}=$value;
 }
my @tags;
my @values;
for (keys %tags){
   push (@tags, $_);
   push (@values, $tags{$_});
}

open(my $OUTFILE, ">", "test.csv")
    or die "Unable to open testfile for writing : $!";
print $OUTFILE join(",",@tags)."\r\n";
print $OUTFILE join(",",@values)."\r\n";
```

The data that is generated in CSV file is:

[image: First Perl code run]

and then again when I re-ran this code I found something like this:

[image: Second Perl Code Run]

**Questions:**

1. How do I fix the cell id, such that I always get `IMSI` in `Cell A1`
   and also the other output in particular cell?
2. How to I rename each cell header? For example `batterylevel` to be renamed as `Battery Level` or `connectedStatus` to be renamed as `Connected Status`.

Comment: Sidenode: Are you aware that the `id` of an `<input>` is not the identifier that is used by forms? Those use the `name`. Just saying. :)

Comment: @simbabque - Question has been edited. Added the sample HTML code

Comment: I wonder what kind of page this is if there are no names on the inputs. Might it be the Kies Air status page or something similar where a mobile device has a webserver and you can access it from the network? The point is, those columns are not sorted, but they are all present.

Comment: @simbabque - I did not copy the entire html page since I am more concerned with picking out the values from there. If you want to have a look into let me know I will share it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a hash to store the data and are not sorting it when accessing the values. **A hash in Perl is not sorted**. The order of the keys is random and ([at least in recent Perls](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#Hash-overhaul)) you cannot rely on the order. You need to sort the keys yourself. **That is a feature**.

The easiest way to do that is to just hardcode the order, since it looks like you are always expecting the same input. For renaming the columns, just use a hash as a lookup table.

I used [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) because it is well-tested and pretty good at handling even arcane border cases.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
use Text::CSV;

my $html = <<HTML;
<input type=hidden id=imsi value="406E+14" >
<input type=hidden id=batterystatus value="Charging" >
<input type=hidden id=batterylevel value="80&nbsp;%" >
HTML

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new( string => $html );

# mapping for the column headers
my %names = (
    imsi          => 'IMSI',
    batterylevel  => 'Battery Level',
    batterystatus => 'Battery Status',
);

my %tags;
while ( my $tag = $parser->get_tag('input') ) {
    my $id    = $tag->get_attr('id');       # get id attribute value
    my $value = $tag->get_attr('value');    # get value attribute value
    $tags{$id} = $value;
}

# use meaningfull names and sort in the loop
my @headers;
my @values;
foreach my $tag (qw(imsi batterylevel batterystatus)) {
    push @headers, $names{$tag};
    push @values,  $tags{$tag};
}

# create a T::CSV handle with Win line endings
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
  sep_char => ',',
  eol => "\r\n",
  quote_char => q{},
});

# write out headers and values
$csv->print(\*STDOUT, \@headers);
$csv->print(\*STDOUT, \@values);
```

Comment: I am getting an error `Global symbol "@tags" requires explicit package name at htmlparse_test.pl line <some line number>.
Execution of htmlparse_test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: But I am using it, since I need to write the data on csv file. Can you look into that pastebin code?

Comment: Feedback to your pastebin link: move the `open` above the `Text::CSV->new`, replace `\*STDOUT` with `$OUTFILE` (which is better named `$fh`, all-caps names suggest global variables, and it's a handle not a file) and get rid of the `print` `join` line.

Comment: In my answer, Text::CSV is taking care of the CSV file for you. It already does what you want. You can still do your `print` yourself of course. All I did was rename the variable to a more meaningful name. :)